# eventlet issue with ubuntu 20.04 running RYU

Tags: python, gunicorn, ubuntu-20.04, eventlet, ryu

I really need your kind help with this problem.

I recently upgraded ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and with it, I can't run the `ryu` controller that is based on python because it shows this import error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'ALREADY_HANDLED' from 'eventlet.wsgi'(/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/eventlet/wsgi.py)
```

I already tried installing `eventlet 30.2` and upgraded `gunicorn` to last version 20.1

I've been researching for days for different versions of `eventlet 30.2` and `gunicorn` but still nothing. Please help.

I tried the `eventlet 30.2`.

Comment: I see you tried version 30.2,  but have you tried version 0.30.2? See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67409452/gunicorn-importerror-cannot-import-name-already-handled-from-eventlet-wsgi (If this is what you mean, I apologize for the redundancy.)

Answer (score 0):

Altering to `eventlet == 0.30.2` probably fixes the issue.

```
sudo pip3 uninstall eventlet
sudo pip3 install eventlet==0.30.2
```